# Horizontal axis for reference angles

Tags: trigonometry

Why we always take the horizontal axis for reference angles? Is it by convention? Could it have been the y-axis? What advantages do we gain from taking the horizontal axis?

Comment: Some part of it is convention, but there are many applications where angle is measured relative to the horizontal, so it is convenient to use the "horizontal" axis.  There are situations where angle is measured relative to the vertical, and we use the $ \ y-$ axis as the reference.  At least as important is the convention that positive angles are defined to be measured in the _counter-clockwise_ direction, which is just as conventional, and likely an example of the "tyranny of right-handedness".

Comment: Yet another convention: you could perfectly have x>0 and y>0 in any [quadrant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrant_%28plane_geometry%29), not necessarily the usual one. Screen images are an example where this convention is not followed, since usually the low $y$ are at the top of the screen.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner Can you point to some resources where i can find more information about using y-axis for reference angles? I could not find anything on the internet. And which are those applications where it is convenient to use the x-axis?

Comment: It would be difficult to suggest any specific reference: any number of books on trigonometry that discuss applications of it would have examples of angles measured with respect to either horizontal or vertical reference directions.  Examples of using the $ \ x-$ axis as reference would be the angle of an inclined plane or the launch angle of a projectile.  The use of the $ \ y-$ axis would appear in discussion of a ladder leaned against a wall, the angle of a support wire for an antenna tower, or the angle of a pendulum.